# PersistenceObjectException in child entity with @MapsId annotation in a test

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following two entities, Parent and Child. Parent does not have a field child.

The child entity is defined like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Audited
public class Child extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_id")
    @MapsId
    @NotAudited
    private Parent parent;
....
```

I am writing a test, and I want to create a parent entity and a child entity, and save both. So I do the following:

```
parentRepository.save(parent);

Child child = new Child(parent);
childService.save(child);
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: io.manuel.Parent; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: io.manuel.Parent
```

The thing is, if I remove the annotation @MapsId, it works. What do I have to do to make it work with the annotation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it this way

```
Parent savedParent = parentRepository.save(parent);

Child child = new Child(savedParent);
childService.save(child);
```

You have to get hold of the persisted object and use it. That is what the exception says, you are passing a detached(not persistent) entity to save. Here is a nice picture of different states an entity can be.

[image]